# Cannot find SQL Instance name on network PC

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, networking

I have been facing this type of situation a dozen of times now and final want a permanent solution to it.

### Problem

Cannot find Server PC's SQL Instance name on client PC.
**Note**:- I have installed SQL Express And Management Studio on both server and client
**Server PC Name** : M-PC
**Server SQL Version** : SQL Server 2008
**Client PC Name** : SHIVANG
**Client SQL Version** : SQL Server 2008
Client's PC SQL Server Screenshot
[image]

### Solution that i have tried

1) **Switching OFF firewall** of both server and client PC completely (Domain, Private & Public)
2) Enabling and restarting the services : **SQL Server** and **Browser Service**
[image]
3) Enabling SQL Network Configuration settings
[image]
4) Also enabled "Allow remote connection" from SQL Server of both the PC
5) Networking between both the PC is perfect can access files through network of both the PC.
6) Even changed the IP configuration settings from obtain to static of both the PC (*IP of Server is 192.168.1.41 and IP of client is 192.168.1.44*)
[image]
7) I have completely uninstalled SQL Express and Management Studio from client and server and installed it again.
8) I also told my client to format the PC and then installed SQL Express and Management Studio. Still nothing.
9) They don't have any antivirus on any of the system (to block the connection)

### FUN PART

Now the fun part here is while i was fiddling with the settings of client and server PC. **Server PC started showing the client PC SQL Instance while client PC was still unable to find the server SQL Instance**.

Below image is of Server PC's SQL Server
[image]
Below image is of Client PC's SQL Server
[image]

Here are the following settings i have been fiddling with:-

1. Changed IP from ***Obtain*** to ***Static*** of both the PC's (client and server)
2. Changed the Protocol : TCP/IP of SQL of both the PC's (client and server) [sorry i forgot to get the screenshots of it and was fiddling with it even more when the server PC stopped showing the client's PC SQL Instance]

Now i don't have a clue what to do next to solve this problem. Please help me if you can.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did u used CMD

Run this

SQLCMD -L
You will get list of SQL Server instance

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader the answer of that is the same as my first image in the question

Comment: Does it works when you restart SQL's browser service? Also have you verified that TCP/IP port 1433 and UDP 1434 are open? The latter is used by browser service to find other instances in the network.

Comment: @pelican_george i restarted the service but nothing and can you give me a screenshot for "TCP/IP port 1433" you are talking about or just share the link in comment.

Comment: Have you tried enabling the TCP/IP protocol of the **sql server network configuration** section? As **Stackfull** said, this will be disabled by default.

Comment: please see the third image in the question there you will see that it is enabled

Comment: Even though they do not show up in the 'Browse' section, can you connect to them by entering the names explicitly in the connection dialog? If not, does it help if you enter the IP addresses and ports? (syntax: name,port or ip-addr,port)

Comment: @deroby i have tried to enter name manually and also tried it with IP and port but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 14):

**There are two levels of security that need to be changed in order to allow remote access**.

1. **SQL Server configuration**: By default in Express, Developer, and
   Enterprise Evaluation editions, connecting by the TCP/IP protocol is disabled. Enable this using SQL Server Configuration Manager.
2. **Windows Firewall:** While disabling the firewall entirely will work
   for this component, doing so is not a security best-practice (nor is it
   required). (Note: in this section, I assume a default
   configuration. There are many settings that can be changed which
   affect these steps slightly.)

There are two cases depending on the type of SQL Server instance you're connecting to:

1. **Default instance (connect by computer name only).** Add an allow
   incoming rule either on **TCP port 1433** or the database engine service
   .
2. **Named instance (connect by computer name + instance name)**. Add an
   allow incoming rule on **UDP port 1434** to access to the SQL Browser
   service. Add an allow incoming rule on the database engine service.

   - [Microsoft Step by Step Tutorial to Getting Started With DB
     Sharing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345306(v=sql.100).aspx)
   - [Reference Stack](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48667/how-to-access-a-sql-server-database-from-other-computer-connected-to-the-same-wo)
   - [A Youtube Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIovZluNmNs)

Comment: For your first point you can see my image 3 that i have enabled TCP/IP. For your second point Firewall currently is not the issue so i completely shut it down to just get the request going to and from from server to client and vice-versa

Comment: @Agent_Spock  Yes I see you completely shut it down,  I think all problem in your PC/Server, As you able to see client server in your server Instance. 

So do all over again and **don't turn off firewall, please create a new rule for that**, Allow port 1433 

[Please follow it ](https://kristofmattei.be/2010/06/21/enabling-sql-server-2008-r2-access-over-network/)

I hope your issue be solved after this, else let me know :) cheers!!

Comment: redoing everything would just be a waste as firewall is not in the picture as it is completely closed.....still, i tried and i can see the same error.

Comment: @Agent_Spock:  Please check this video and verify that your local machine able to access it, and try with public IP and after that try on the client !
And Please let me know if this also not work !!, However, I'm having SQL 2016 So My interface different.  (Upgrading SQL is another option but let see)

Cheers!

Comment: i have already seen that video and everything is done accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a definitive answer for your inconsistent results but I do have some background information that may help you troubleshoot the problem.

SQL instances are enumerated using the [SQL Server Resolution Protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219703.aspx). This is an application layer protocol that uses UDP (not TCP) to send enumeration requests to servers on the local subnet and receive responses as shown in the [communication flow for multi-instance discovery diagram](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219709.aspx). It is the SQL Server Browser services that listens on UDP port 1434 to handle enumeration requests.

Importantly, ***the UDP multicast protocol does not guarantee requests or responses are delivered***.  Consequently, loss may occur that can only be detected by a network trace.  The SQL Server Resolution Protocol cannot know why no response was received; it could be because a server is down, network problem, firewall, SQL instance hidden, etc.  Also UDP multicast requests are delivered only to devices on the local subnet so resolution is limited to those machines.

The PowerShell script below sends a UDP request to a specific host. You can run this to ensure the SQL Browser service responds with the expected information about the instance(s) on the host.

```
Function List-Instances($hostName)
{

    Write-Host ("Retrieving information from SQL Server Browser service on host $HostName ...");

    try
    {
        $udpClient = new-object Net.Sockets.UdpClient($HostName, 1434);
        $bufferLength =  1;
        $browserQueryMessage = new-object byte[] $bufferLength;
        $browserQueryMessage[0] = 2; # list all instances
        $bytesSent = $udpClient.Send($browserQueryMessage, $browserQueryMessage.Length);
        $udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;
        $remoteEndPoint = new-object System.Net.IPEndPoint([System.Net.IPAddress]::Broadcast, 0);
        $browserResponse = $udpClient.Receive([ref]$remoteEndPoint);
        $payloadLength = $browserResponse.Length - 3;
        $browserResponseString = [System.Text.ASCIIEncoding]::ASCII.GetString($browserResponse, 3, $payloadLength);
        $browserResponseString
        $elements = $browserResponseString.Split(";");
        $elements
        $namedInstancePort = "";
        Write-host "SQL Browser Data:" -ForegroundColor Green;
        $i = 0;
        while($i -lt $elements.Length)
        {
            if([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($elements[$i]))
            {
                Write-Host "";
                $i += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host $("    " + $elements[$i] + "=" + $elements[$i+1]) -ForegroundColor Green;
                $i += 2;
            }
        }
    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
        Write-host $("ERROR: " + $_.Exception.Message) -ForegroundColor Red;
    }

}

# send request to SQL Brower service to enumerate all SQL instances running on specific host
List-Instances -hostName "SomeMachine";
```

In summary, successful resolution requires:

- SQL Server Browser Service must be running
- UDP port 1434 must be allowed through the firewall
- The servers must be on the same subnet
- No UDP packet loss
- The servers respond in a timely manner

Comment: Regarding with your summary 1) SQL server browser service is running and also restarted it couple of times 2) no issue with firewall as it is completely turned off for the time being (both in client and server) 3) The server and client are on same network and can easily transfer FILES from both end and i pinged both of them and the ping is consistent and no request timeout can be seen. 4) regarding UDP packet loss can you show me an image or something so i can get an idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @Agent_Spock, you'll need to use a tool like Wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) to capture the UDP network traffic. Did you try the PowerShell script?

Comment: @Dan_Guzman i dont know how to use PowerShell script? even if i knew what am i supposed to do?

Comment: Was the SQL Server Browser Service for me. The service was disabled by default; enabled & started, and it popped up on the "Network Servers" tab instantly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, confirm the firewall settings. Install SQL Server Management Studio on a non-host LAN computer and check that you can connect using the IP address of the host. This may mean messing around with logon rights if SA is not enabled on the host server.

SQL Server Services > SQL Server Browser > Right Click > Properties > Service > Start Mode > Automatic.

SQL Server Services > SQL Server Browser > Right Click > Properties > Start

Open command prompt on host and/or LAN computer and execute:

```
sqlcmd -L
```

Answer (score -1):

When you install SQL Express , you can't access it from network or remotely.
unless you configure the remote access option

1 - In Object Explorer, right-click a server and select Properties.

2 - Click the Connections node.

3 - Under Remote server connections, select or clear the Allow remote connections       to this server check box.

Comment: please my dear friend read the full question. Read the 4th point it says i have already done that.